# PySpark Using collect_list to collect Arrays of Varying Length

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker

I am attempting to use collect_list to collect arrays (and maintain order) from two different data frames.

Test_Data and Train_Data have the same format.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('Group').orderBy('date')

# Train_Data has 4 data points
# Test_Data has 7 data points
# desired target array:         [1, 1, 2, 3]
# desired MarchMadInd array:    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

sorted_list_diff_array_lens = train_data.withColumn('target', 
F.collect_list('target').over(w)
                                  )\
test_data.withColumn('MarchMadInd', F.collect_list('MarchMadInd').over(w))\
   .groupBy('Group')\
   .agg(F.max('target').alias('target'), 
    F.max('MarchMadInd').alias('MarchMadInd')
)
```

I realize the syntax is incorrect with "test_data.withColumn", but I want to select the array for the *MarchMadInd* from the **test_date**, but the array for the *target* from the **train_data**. The desired output would look like the following:

```
{"target":[1, 1, 2, 3], "MarchMadInd":[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
```

Context: this is for a DeepAR time series model (using AWS) that requires dynamic features to include the prediction period, but the target should be historical data.

Comment: You will need a key on which to join the two dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involves using a join as recommended by pault.

1. Create a dataframe with dynamic features of length equal to Training + Prediction period
2. Create a dataframe with target values of length equal to just the Training period.
3. Use a LEFT JOIN (with the dynamic feature data on LEFT) to bring these dataframes together

Now, using collect_list will create the desired result.